# Apache Flink Zookeeper Checkpoint Conflict After Upgrade

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I recently upgraded an Apache Flink cluster from 1.3.2 to 1.4.2 and now I get following exception in Zookeeper Logs

```
2018-06-19 18:45:34,658 [myid:3] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x363f3574f420001 type:create cxid:0x2284d zxid:0x900016e9d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/flink/cluster_one/checkpoints/5e8ad58b9f2ef81b155d0e15b23d2365/0000000000000010305/81783429-1405-4609-9cdb-ce9dc95b8272 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /flink/cluster_one/checkpoints/5e8ad58b9f2ef81b155d0e15b23d2365/0000000000000010305/81783429-1405-4609-9cdb-ce9dc95b8272
```

Because of this the Apache Flink node where this is thrown is repeatedly kicked out of the cluster and then rejoins.

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/user/taskmanager#-50864731]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.JobManagerMessages$LeaderSessionMessage".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    ... 1 more

06/22/2018 16:11:29 Job execution switched to status FAILING.
java.lang.Exception: Cannot deploy task Source: Custom Source -> StringToJSONEvents (1/1) (a78bb6a5d7c90a7b5cee785bc4ac2426) - TaskManager (37d2c90dd316c87974dda50e0b4525d6 @ tm03-dev (dataPort=6125)) not responding after a timeout of 10000 ms
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$deploy$3(Execution.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/user/taskmanager#-50864731]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.JobManagerMessages$LeaderSessionMessage".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    ... 1 more
06/22/2018 16:11:29 FilterLoginFailedEvents -> Sink: SendRequestToService(1/1) switched to CANCELING 
06/22/2018 16:11:29 FilterLoginFailedEvents -> Sink: SendRequestToService(1/1) switched to CANCELED
```

In TaskManager logs this keeps repeating

```
2018-06-22 15:59:45.168 [main-SendThread(ip-10-11-21-15.domain:2181)] DEBUG o.a.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x163f3574f380005 after 0ms
2018-06-22 15:59:58.513 [main-SendThread(ip-10-11-21-15.domain:2181)] DEBUG o.a.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x163f3574f380005 after 0ms
2018-06-22 16:00:10.658 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8172] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229/user/jobmanager (attempt 9305, timeout: 30000 milliseconds)
2018-06-22 16:00:11.858 [main-SendThread(ip-10-11-21-15.domain:2181)] DEBUG o.a.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x163f3574f380005 after 0ms
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] DEBUG akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-15 - Association between local [tcp://flink@tm03-flink-dev:25422] and remote [tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229] was disassociated because the ProtocolStateActor failed: Unknown
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] DEBUG akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-15 - Association between local [tcp://flink@tm03-flink-dev:25422] and remote [tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229] was disassociated because the ProtocolStateActor failed: Unknown
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-15 - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-15 - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] DEBUG akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport New I/O worker #2 - Remote connection to [flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com/10.11.21.24:26229] was disconnected because of [id: 0x735f1b8b, /10.11.21.13:25422 :> flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com/10.11.21.24:26229] DISCONNECTED
2018-06-22 16:00:14.971 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9313] DEBUG akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport New I/O worker #2 - Remote connection to [flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com/10.11.21.24:26229] was disconnected because of [id: 0x735f1b8b, /10.11.21.13:25422 :> flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com/10.11.21.24:26229] DISCONNECTED
2018-06-22 16:00:25.199 [main-SendThread(ip-10-11-21-15.domain:2181)] DEBUG o.a.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x163f3574f380005 after 0ms
2018-06-22 16:00:38.539 [main-SendThread(ip-10-11-21-15.domain:2181)] DEBUG o.a.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x163f3574f380005 after 0ms
2018-06-22 16:00:40.679 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8172] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager  - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager01-flink-dev.domain.com:26229/user/jobmanager (attempt 9306, timeout: 30000 milliseconds)
```

Another clue, on the leader JobManager such 2 messages are displayed in the log every few seconds:

```
2018-06-27 17:33:46.632 [jobmanager-future-thread-2] DEBUG o.a.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.metrics.MetricFetcher  - Could not retrieve QueryServiceGateway.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/), Path(/user/MetricQueryService_64bde0e9e6f3f0a906a30e88c261c9d7)]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:442)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:83)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.failure(Promise.scala:104)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:157)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:68)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:66)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:76)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:120)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:75)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:534)
        at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:558)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:595)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:584)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:98)
        at akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor$$anonfun$gated$1.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:353)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
        at akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:203)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/), Path(/user/MetricQueryService_64bde0e9e6f3f0a906a30e88c261c9d7)]
        ... 27 common frames omitted



2018-06-27 17:34:01.625 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.RuntimeMonitorHandler  - Error while handling request.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.NotFoundException: Could not find job 93d6fa4fb5b2355bb03253cb80d81ef5.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.AbstractExecutionGraphRequestHandler.lambda$handleJsonRequest$0(AbstractExecutionGraphRequestHandler.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.ExecutionGraphCache.lambda$getExecutionGraph$0(ExecutionGraphCache.java:130)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:444)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:259)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:83)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:534)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(MemoryArchivist.scala:123)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist.aroundReceive(MemoryArchivist.scala:65)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.NotFoundException: Could not find job 93d6fa4fb5b2355bb03253cb80d81ef5.
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

What does this exception mean?
 Are we supposed to erase contents of Zookeeper folders (high-availability.zookeeper.path.root) before upgrade?

Comment: Are you sure that the node is kicked out of the cluster because of this? This is `INFO` log level. Could you maybe share the logs of the respective node with us?

Comment: Yes, in fact that TM doesn't accept any jobs:

Comment: It says time out. I updated the logs. This message "... Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for ..." was never in 1.3.2 or maybe so seldom no one noticed it. Now we get one every few minutes, all on same TM.

Comment: Could you please post the complete cluster entrypoint logs and the logs of the rejected `TaskManager`?

Comment: That might take a while as I need to obfuscate host / application details. But I added the section which keeps repeating, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

This question was related to [Apache Flink 1.4.2 akka.actor.ActorNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067124/apache-flink-1-4-2-akka-actor-actornotfound).

After we

restarted the JobManagers
 increased TaskManager Memory size from 1GB to 2GB

The issue seems to be gone and the cluster is working fine now.