# Apache Flink 1.4.2 akka.actor.ActorNotFound

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

After upgrading to Apache Flink 1.4.2 we get following errors every few seconds on one TaskManager out of 3.

```
2018-06-27 17:33:46.632 [jobmanager-future-thread-2] DEBUG o.a.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.metrics.MetricFetcher  - Could not retrieve QueryServiceGateway.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/), Path(/user/MetricQueryService_64bde0e9e6f3f0a906a30e88c261c9d7)]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:442)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:83)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.failure(Promise.scala:104)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:157)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:68)
        at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:66)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:76)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:120)
        at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:75)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:534)
        at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:558)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:595)
        at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:584)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:98)
        at akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor$$anonfun$gated$1.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:353)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
        at akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:203)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/), Path(/user/MetricQueryService_64bde0e9e6f3f0a906a30e88c261c9d7)]
        ... 27 common frames omitted



2018-06-27 17:34:01.625 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.RuntimeMonitorHandler  - Error while handling request.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.NotFoundException: Could not find job 93d6fa4fb5b2355bb03253cb80d81ef5.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.AbstractExecutionGraphRequestHandler.lambda$handleJsonRequest$0(AbstractExecutionGraphRequestHandler.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.ExecutionGraphCache.lambda$getExecutionGraph$0(ExecutionGraphCache.java:130)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:444)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:259)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:256)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:186)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:183)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:83)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:534)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(MemoryArchivist.scala:123)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist.aroundReceive(MemoryArchivist.scala:65)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.NotFoundException: Could not find job 93d6fa4fb5b2355bb03253cb80d81ef5.
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

The respective TaskManager disappears and reappears in the cluster but no job can be successfully run on it.

Trying to run a job on this TaskManager gives

```
TaskManager (64bde0e9e6f3f0a906a30e88c261c9d7 @ tm03-dev (dataPort=6125)) not responding after a timeout of 10000 ms
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$deploy$3(Execution.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124/user/taskmanager#-636625535]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.JobManagerMessages$LeaderSessionMessage".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
```

Also the TaskManager seems to send no heartbeat response back to the JobManager

```
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm01-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm01-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm02-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm02-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.462 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7 - Sending Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.463 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Received heartbeat rsp from [akka.tcp://flink@tm02-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.463 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Received heartbeat rsp from [akka.tcp://flink@tm02-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.463 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Received heartbeat rsp from [akka.tcp://flink@tm01-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.463 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG akka.remote.RemoteWatcher flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Received heartbeat rsp from [akka.tcp://flink@tm01-dev:6124]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.653 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124]] Caused by: [tm03-dev: Name or service not known]
2018-06-28 08:07:52.653 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@tm03-dev:6124]] Caused by: [tm03-dev: Name or service not known]
```

The cluster was recreated from scratch with the same results. This was not happening for 1.3.2

What can be causing this?

Comment: Could you please share the complete logs of the failing TaskManager @razvan?

Comment: Hi Till, I'd rather avoid that since it's sensitive data also in there but, it was not reproduced in 1 week so far (after JobManager restart) Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

We did a couple of things here after which the error disappeared:

We restarted the JobManagers

We increased TaskManager Memory size from 1GB to 2GB.

I can't explain it, but for now error is not showing up anymore since few weeks and all seems fine